# SVM code can't recognize the date time column

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I followed this article to build an SVM model on my data.
https://stackabuse.com/implementing-svm-and-kernel-svm-with-pythons-scikit-learn/

here a sample of my data:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hyGn.png)

the problem is when I run the code this error appeared:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '10/29/2020 8:30'
```

Comment: strings are not suitable as SVM input features. They should be converted to float variables. Or you can run SVM after except them from your data.

Comment: the time is really important, regard the "convert them to float variables", you mean 10292929830? if not, can you tell me how?

Comment: please do not post your code/samples as image. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your date to timestamp and handle it accordingly.

```
import datetime

s = '10/29/2020 8:30'
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
date = date.timestamp()
```

`date` will now be `1603953000.0`.

Edit: if you want to covert pandas dataframe columns, here's a toy example.

```
import pandas as pd

s = '10/29/2020 8:30'
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[s, s, s]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype('int64')
```

output:

```
                  Date
0  1603960200000000000
1  1603960200000000000
2  1603960200000000000
```

Comment: thank you veery muuch for your response, another maybe silly question, if I have a column how can I pass it to datetime.datetime.strptime function?

Comment: I edited my answer. If your problem is solved, mark it as accepted for future viewers.

Comment: i really appreciate your help! for sure I will